# Read a CSV file, manipulate it, use as input to GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, csv, google-maps-api-3

I'm still looking for help with this issue. I'm pretty new at all this and would really appreciate any help the more experienced can lend.  Thanks..

An example of the file I'm trying to read can be seen here; http://arhab.org/FlightDetails/UMHAB-27.csv This is a static file as far as the user is concerned. They do not have the ability to choose it.

I need to create an array usable by GoogleMaps in the following format;

```
var flightPath = [
{name: "Start",  latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(39.206718, -94.607391), course: 221.0, speed: 15.0},
{name: " ",      latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(38.291982, -96.821856), course: 221.0, speed: 15.0},
{name: "End",    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(39.206718, -97.607391), course: 221.0, speed: 15.0}
];
```

After looking at a lot of CSV to Array functions I don't seem to be able to get any of them working correctly. Someone must have a javascript function that will let me put it into the array format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are fetching CSV from a file input:

[image]

For this way, you could use this code to read the CSV file line line:

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

  var file = this.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    // Entire file
    console.log(this.result);

    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      console.log(lines[line]);
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

Comment: Actually the file will be pre-selected (if you will) the user won't be able to choose. Well, maybe someday but not for what I'm doing now.

Comment: please specify in question how you are fetching the file